# Animation frame not rotating correctly

Tags: c#, animation, xna

So when my ship was just a texture, i would click on the screen, the ship would face that click point and slowly travel towards it, only stopping when the middle of the texture reached said point (what i wanted). So now i try to animate it. The animation is working fine, but now the ship wont face the direction of the position i click on, it faces a few degrees to either the left or right, and the ship travels to the point but when it stops its never at the exact point like it did when it was just a texture, instead it always stops a bit away from it.

My animation class

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace AsteroidAvoider
{
    class Animation
    {
        float rotation;

        // The image representing the collection of images used for animation
        Texture2D spriteStrip;

        // The scale used to display the sprite strip
        float scale;

        // The time since we last updated the frame
        int elapsedTime;

        // The time we display a frame until the next one
        int frameTime;

        // The number of frames that the animation contains
        int frameCount;

        // The index of the current frame we are displaying
        int currentFrame;

        // The color of the frame we will be displaying
        Color color;

        // The area of the image strip we want to display
        Rectangle sourceRect = new Rectangle();

        // The area where we want to display the image strip in the game
        Rectangle destinationRect = new Rectangle();

        // Width of a given frame
        public int FrameWidth;

        // Height of a given frame
        public int FrameHeight;

        // The state of the Animation
        public bool Active;

        // Determines if the animation will keep playing or deactivate after one run
        public bool Looping;

        public Vector2 Position;

        public void Initialize(Texture2D texture, Vector2 position, int frameWidth, int frameHeight, int frameCount, int frametime, Color color, float scale, bool looping)
        {

            // Keep a local copy of the values passed in
            this.color = color;
            this.FrameWidth = frameWidth;
            this.FrameHeight = frameHeight;
            this.frameCount = frameCount;
            this.frameTime = frametime;
            this.scale = scale;

            Looping = looping;
            Position = position;
            spriteStrip = texture;

            // Set the time to zero
            elapsedTime = 0;
            currentFrame = 0;

            // Set the Animation to active by default
            Active = true;
        }

        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Do not update the game if we are not active
            if (Active == false)
                return;

            // Update the elapsed time
            elapsedTime += (int)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;

            // If the elapsed time is larger than the frame time
            // we need to switch frames
            if (elapsedTime > frameTime)
            {
                // Move to the next frame
                currentFrame++;

                // If the currentFrame is equal to frameCount reset currentFrame to zero
                if (currentFrame == frameCount)
                {
                    currentFrame = 0;
                    // If we are not looping deactivate the animation
                    if (Looping == false)
                        Active = false;
                }

                // Reset the elapsed time to zero
                elapsedTime = 0;
            }

            // Grab the correct frame in the image strip by multiplying the currentFrame index by the frame width
            sourceRect = new Rectangle(currentFrame * FrameWidth, 0, FrameWidth, FrameHeight);

            // Grab the correct frame in the image strip by multiplying the currentFrame index by the frame width
            destinationRect = new Rectangle((int)Position.X - (int)(FrameWidth * scale) / 2,
            (int)Position.Y - (int)(FrameHeight * scale) / 2,
            (int)(FrameWidth * scale),
            (int)(FrameHeight * scale));
        }

        // Draw the Animation Strip
        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, float rotation)
        {
            this.rotation = rotation;

            // Only draw the animation when we are active
            if (Active)
            {
                //spriteBatch.Draw(spriteStrip, destinationRect, sourceRect, color);

                spriteBatch.Draw(spriteStrip, destinationRect, sourceRect, color, rotation, new Vector2(100, 75), SpriteEffects.None, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My player class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace AsteroidAvoider
{
    class Player
    {
        public Vector2 position, distance, mousePosition;
        public float speed;
        public float rotation;
        public MouseState mouseState;
        public bool canMove = false;
        Animation playerAnimation;

        public Player(Animation playerAnimation, Vector2 position, float speed)
        {
            this.playerAnimation = playerAnimation;
            this.position = position;
            this.speed = speed;
            playerAnimation = new Animation();
        }

        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            mouseState = Mouse.GetState();

            float speedForThisFrame = speed;

            if (mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                mousePosition.X = mouseState.X;
                mousePosition.Y = mouseState.Y;
            }

            if ((mousePosition - position).Length() < speed)
                speedForThisFrame = 0;

            if ((mousePosition - position).Length() > speed)
                speedForThisFrame = 2.0f;

            distance = mousePosition - position;
            distance.Normalize();

            rotation = (float)Math.Atan2(distance.Y, distance.X);

            //position += distance * speedForThisFrame;

            if (speedForThisFrame == 0)
                position = mousePosition;
            else
                position += distance * speedForThisFrame;

            playerAnimation.Position = position;
            playerAnimation.Update(gameTime);
        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            playerAnimation.Draw(spriteBatch, rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

My game1 class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace AsteroidAvoider
{
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        Player player;
        Texture2D playerImage;
        Animation playerAnimation;
        Vector2 playerPosition = new Vector2(550, 550);
        float playerSpeed = 2f;
        ParallaxingBackground bg;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1500;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 600;
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            Animation playerAnimation = new Animation();
            playerImage = Content.Load<Texture2D>("player");
            player = new Player(playerAnimation, playerPosition, playerSpeed);

            playerAnimation.Initialize(playerImage, playerPosition, 200, 150, 4, 30, Color.White, 1f, true);
            this.IsMouseVisible = true;

            bg = new ParallaxingBackground();
            bg.Initialize(Content, "background", GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, -1);
            base.Initialize();
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here

        }

        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            // TODO: Add your update logic here
            player.Update(gameTime);
            bg.Update();

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            spriteBatch.Begin();
            // TODO: Add your drawing code here
            bg.Draw(spriteBatch);
            player.Draw(spriteBatch);
            spriteBatch.End();
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your spaceship faces a few degrees to either the left or right I think it means that your `sourceRectangle` parameter of your `spriteBatch.Draw` is not correct.

For your second problem, that when the spaceship stops it's never at the exact point, you have to manually set its position when it is near the `mousePosition`, because setting `speedForThisFrame = 0` can't ensure you that it's in the right position, you still have an uncertainty of `(mousePosition - position).Length()`.

**EDIT**

I mean something like this:

```
if (speedForThisFrame == 0)
  position = mousePosition;
else
  position += distance * speedForThisFrame;
```

assuming that `position` is centered in the bow of your spaceship sprite, or wherever you need.

**EDIT 2**

When your `position` is the same as `mousePosition` XNA doesn't let you to `Normalize` a `Vector2` whose lenght is 0. So try something like this:

```
if (mousePosition != position)
{
   distance = mousePosition - position;
   distance.Normalize();

   rotation = (float)Math.Atan2(distance.Y, distance.X);
}
```

in this way your `rotation` will remain the same it was before the spaceship reached `mousePosition`.

Comment: Ive messed around with the sourceRectangle and i cannot fix it if thats the problem, as for the the speedForThisFrame = 0 that is because if i dont have this the image goes over the mouse position, then realizes its gone over, goes back, goes over so on so forth and creates a jerking effect on the image. The speedForThisFrame is not the problem, it works when i don't include the rotation in the animation classes draw()

Comment: You didn't understand, you don't have to remove it, you need to set the positon of your spaceship when you set `speedForThisFrame = 0` because you have an uncertainty of `(mousePosition - position).Length()` and you don't know where you actually are.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, what do you put and where?

Comment: This had some very strange results, when space ship hits the mouse (which it still doesnt do for some reason) it flies off the map :/

Comment: When i put in a breakpoint i cant play the game, how do i play the game while showing all the values at the bottom that show up when i put in a breakpoint? (as you can tell im relatively new to this :P)

Comment: You should put a breakpoint on the line `position = mousePosition`, and see what value you have. If you want to show some values in output use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()`.

Comment: i checked, the position does get set to the mouse position

Comment: But why does it fly off the map? What value did you get in that moment?

Comment: according to the breakpoint, it didnt fly off the map, the image just doesnt show up, as the position is on the screen, as is the position of the mouse and the position of both rects

Comment: Have you checked only the first frame or the succeeding, too? Update your question with the changed code, maybe there's something wrong.

Comment: Succeeding, mouse position and position are the same, updated.

Comment: Maybe I've found the problem, you're checking `distance = mousePosition - position` and then you call `distance.Normalize` that you use to compute the rotation, but if that vector has no length the normalization makes it have infinite length. Try to use `speed` instead of `distance` in your `Atan2`.

Comment: Atan requires an x and y, speed is only a float so i dont know how id put that in instead of distance

Comment: Aww, sorry, I thought it was a Vector2. I'll edit my answer again.

Comment: Worked fine :) thanks. The way i initialized the bounds were also the problem.